# Symbol emission for inlined private member functions

Tags: c++, gcc, visibility, linkage

Suppose the following dummy header-source pair gets compiled into a single translation unit, as one would expect.

```cpp
struct foo {
  public:
    int bar(int x);
  private:
    int baz();
};
```

```cpp
int foo::bar(int x) {
    return baz() * 2 - 1;
}
int foo::baz() {
    return 42;
}
```

In every compiler I've used so far, `foo::baz()` is short enough that it gets inlined into `foo::bar(int)`, which is expected. However every single one of them still emits an out-of-line copy of the function, even though in reality it would never be accessible from outside the class (unless the raw symbol is referenced directly or something, as C++ member visibility != symbol visibility). This occurs even with `-fvisibility=hidden` (on compilers that support this flag).

This is partly why I often like to enable LTO because it has the nice side-effect that it will automatically preen (or not emit in the first place) functions like that when they get inlined and never referenced as a symbol (because it would know that hidden symbols that never get referenced anywhere in the binary being linked ought not be emitted at all). With these two things enabled, `foo::baz()` does not get emitted, which is what I want. However, LTO is not something I can enable in every project for one reason or another. My question is thus how to encourage the compiler to not emit these functions without the help of something like LTO.

For context, I am mostly interested in GCC and GCC-like compilers like Clang and MinGW, but if there is a compiler independent way, that would be even better.

Speaking of which, one could use a static non-member function, which will not be emitted out-of-line if it is ever inlined such that an out-of-line copy would never be referenced, but that seems like a rather clunky way to circumvent this problem for obvious reasons (e.g. accessing private members would be more cumbersome). Besides, it's not always my code that is being compiled, so I'd want to mitigate this problem when compiling other people's code, too.

In general, all this is not really a big problem, as such functions, when emitted out-of-line, are probably small or trivial enough that they would be inlined in the first place, and thus would probably not be that big of a waste of space at all in the binary file. Still, it does feel like a bit of extra bits that could use some trimming off.

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4TTdMP) for example source code.